# F2FS vs ext3/ext4

Tags: linux, filesystems, embedded

We are using Beaglebone black Based custom board,
we are planning to use eMMC in our board.
We are in the process of checking different filesystem options,
What are the different file system we can use for eMMC ?
Usage of ext3/ext4 is very famous, but is it worth investing in evaluating Btrfs or F2fs.

We are bit worried when we think of using F2FS file system, because it is being developed by Samsung, we are worried about roadmap of F2FS file system and further update of the same.

What approach should we use to evaluate different filesystems?

Any suggestions/pointers for the same ?

Answer (score 2):

You have a good evaluation of [well-known file systems at Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_raid_fs4&num=1). Well, of course, what you *should* use is entirely up to you as it is hard to not give an opinionated answer.

As for your fears about Samsung, F2FS is open sourced and GPLv2. Hence in any case it'll remain forkable up to a certain point; see what happens with reiser4, for instance — regardless of how people see it, reiser4 is still being developed; slowly but developed still and [patches are available](http://sourceforge.net/projects/reiser4/files/reiser4-for-linux-3.x/) — might be not the best example though ;-). If anything goes wrong with F2FS, it'll most probably forked, depending on its success rate.

Technically speaking F2FS is being developed with eMMC in mind, which makes it very well suited for that kind of storage. Having Samsung behind it also means they are consistently giving man-hours to the development.